# Sampling Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO) with Xcode and Clang

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to do sampling PGO (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#using-sampling-profilers) on Apple platforms? Official Clang implementation expects Linux `perf` profiles. macOS and iOS do not support Linux `perf` so how can I use sampling PGO on these platforms? Is there something ready to use in Xcode Instruments for that? Maybe some converter from Xcode profiler format into Linux `perf` format (that then can be consumed by https://github.com/google/autofdo).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We strongly prefer one question per question as that’s how the site is optimized. Could you rewatch the [tour] and then pick the most easy / primary / beginning question you have and [edit out all the others here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/467182/edit)? It’s perfectly fine to then ask the second and the third and even link them to each other if they are related.

Comment: Okay, I will create separate questions for the second and for the third sub-questions - no problem.